# Will C++ optimize out empty/non-virtual/void method calls?

Tags: c++, templates, optimization

Example code:

```
class DummyLock {
public:
    void lock() {}
    void unlock() {}    

};

...

template <class T>
class List {
    T _lock;

    ...
public:
    void append(void* smth) {
        _lock.lock();

        ...

        _lock.unlock();
    }
};

...
List<DummyLock> l;
l.append(...);
```

So, will it optimize out these method calls if lock type is a templated type? If no, what is the best approach to making a template list that has policies as template arguments (as in Andrei Alexandrescu C++ book)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming inlining is enabled (so "some optimisation turned on"), then yes, any decent compiler should make this sort of thing into zero instructions. Particularly in a template, as templates require [in nearly all of the current compilers, at least] the compiler to "see" the source of the object. In a non-templated sitution, then it's possible to come up with a scenario where you are "out of line" declaring the empty `lock` code, and the compiler can't know that the function is empty.

(Looks scary with `void *smth` in your `append` tho' - I hope you do intent to have that as a second template type in your real implementation)

As always when it comes to "does the compiler do this", if it's really important, you need to check that YOUR compiler does what you expect in this particular case. `clang++ -S` or `g++ -S` would for example show if there are calls made or not within your `append` function.

Comment: Yeah, I don't plan leaving void* hanging around, I just wrote one template argument for the sake of simplicity.

Thanks, I'll try that -S g++ flag in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any real-world C++ compiler (i.e. gcc, cland, VC++), will output no code for empty inline functions when optimization is turned on.